# Getting error in calling Store procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a SP that works when I execute from SQL Server Management Studio. However, when I call from my code:

```
Database.SqlQuery<Response>("cw.SpGetCompanyLimits @user_id, @company_id",
    new SqlParameter("@user_id", userId),
    new SqlParameter("@company_id", companyId)).Single();
```

I get the exception: `InvalidOperationException: The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

I don't understand why this is happening, because my variables are `int` and they are defined as `int` in the SP as well.

The SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cw.SpGetCompanyLimits
    @company_id             INT=2,
    @user_id                INT=13
AS BEGIN

DECLARE
@exchange_rate          DECIMAL(19,2),
@dollars_auth_amount    DECIMAL(19,2),
@bols_auth_amount       DECIMAL(19,2),
@auth_limit             DECIMAL(19,2),
@dollars_amount         DECIMAL(19,2),
@bols_amount            DECIMAL(19,2),
@company_limit          DECIMAL(19,2),
@spent_bols             DECIMAL(19,2),
@spent_dollars          DECIMAL(19,2),
@current_date           CHAR(8)

SELECT DISTINCT @auth_limit = Amount FROM Limits WHERE Id = @user_id

SELECT @company_limit = DailyLimit FROM Companies WHERE Id = @company_id

SELECT TOP 1  @exchange_rate = Sale FROM ExchangeRates ORDER BY Date DESC

SET @current_date = CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

SELECT @dollars_amount = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD' THEN Amount END), 0.00) ,
   @bols_amount = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'BOL' THEN Amount END), 0.00)          
FROM ProcessBatches
WHERE CompanyId = @company_id AND
  CAST(DateProcess as date) = @current_date AND
  Currency IN ('BOL', 'USD') AND
  OperationTypeId NOT IN (17, 18) AND
  OperationStatusId IN (3, 4, 5, 6);

SELECT @dollars_auth_amount = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD' THEN Amount END), 0.00) ,
   @bols_auth_amount = COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Currency = 'BOL' THEN Amount END), 0.00)          
FROM ProcessBatches PB, AuthorizedBatches AB
WHERE CompanyId = @company_id AND
  CAST(DateProcess as date) = @current_date AND
  Currency IN ('BOL', 'USD') AND
  AB.Id = @user_id AND
  OperationTypeId NOT IN (17, 18) AND
  PB.OperationStatusId IN (3, 4, 5, 6);

SELECT 
    @company_limit AS CompanyLimit,
    @auth_limit AS AuthorizerLimit,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,2), (@company_limit - (@dollars_amount + @bols_amount / @exchange_rate))) AS Available,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,2), (@dollars_amount + @bols_amount / @exchange_rate)) AS SpentMoney,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,2), (@dollars_auth_amount + @bols_auth_amount / @exchange_rate)) AS AuthorizedLimit,
@bols_amount AS BolsCompany,
@dollars_amount AS DollarsCompany
END
```

Comment: what are the parameters values passed to the SP? Can you show where are u declaring the variables (userId, conpanyId)?

Comment: What type is the return value?  i.e. Are any of the fields on Response defined as decimal?

Comment: Also, when you run this command in SSMS, are any of the fields returned null?  If so, what data type are they?

Comment: @Coding It's a simple assignment, `int userId = UserInfo.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
           int companyId = UserInfo.Identity.GetCompanyId();`

Comment: plz show your SP?

Comment: @ JohnLBevan Response is a model class with the same fields that SP returns, and all are decimal

Comment: my guess would be that a query filling the first couple values is returning a null value.   auth_limit company_limit exchange_rate

Comment: The issue is in the sp, not in the code.

Comment: @Coding When I run the sp in the sql server, it returns the values correctly (no nulls).

Comment: please give us the code of the Response Model.   Also, it doesnt matter whether the data coming from the SP contains null.  The system figures out whether it MAY EVER, or COULD Ever return a null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The solution was simple. I was not sending the parameters in order, and the values `user_id` and `company_id` were null (that is what I understood). So, I changed this

```
Database.SqlQuery<Response>("cw.SpGetCompanyLimits @user_id, @company_id",
    new SqlParameter("@user_id", userId),
    new SqlParameter("@company_id", companyId)).Single();
```

to this

```
Database.SqlQuery<Response>("cw.SpGetCompanyLimits @user_id, @company_id",
    new SqlParameter("@company_id", companyId),
    new SqlParameter("@user_id", userId)).Single();
```

Now, it works. I didn't know that the order of the parameters was important. Thanks for your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices here:

In your Response model, make the field types decimal? so that they are nullable.  This may or may not be desirable for your business case.

Or, ensure that null results from your query get set to a default so that they are not returned as nulls.

I personally recommend option #1.  Then you can handle null values in code instead of trying to manipulate what appears to be a straight forward GET from your database.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your post that you think that the parameters you are providing are throwing the exception. It is probably the returned data that is not matching your Response model.

Your model should look something like this, using `Nullable<decimal>` or maybe `Nullable<float>` .  P.S. "Response" is not a good class name!

```
public class Response
{
    public Nullable<decimal> CompanyLimit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AuthorizerLimit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> BolsCompany { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DollarsCompany { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Available { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SpentMoney { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AuthorizedLimit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it. `Response` was just as example, actually my class has another name, but thanks for your advice.